# R: Evaluating and Plotting Functions Over a Grid

Tags: r, function, plot, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I have the following function :

```
#function

my_function_b <- function(input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4) {

final_value = sin(input_1) + cos(input_2) + input_3 + input_4
 
}
```

**Question**:

- For "my_function_b", I am trying to evaluate "final_value" for different values of "input_1", "input_2", "input_3" and "input_4" . E.g. input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4 from 1 to 100 at increments of 0.1.
- Then, I want to make a 3 Dimensional plot with "input_1", "input_2" and "input_3".
- Next, I want to a fit a 3 Dimensional surface over this plot
- Finally, I want to "color" this 3 Dimensional surface according to the values of "final_input"

**What I tried so far:**

I figured out how to make a "grid frame" for the second function and then evaluate "final_value" using this "grid frame", e.g.

```
#create grid and evaluate function
input_1 <- seq(0,100,0.1)
input_2 <- seq(0,100,0.1)
input_3 <- seq(0,100,0.1)
input_4 <- seq(0,100,0.1)

my_grid <- data.frame(input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4)
my_grid$final_value = sin(input_1) + cos(input_2) + input_3 + input_4
```

But I am not sure if this is the best way to solve this question. This is now creating problems when I try to plot the results, e.g.

```
#make a 3d plot for two of the inputs and the output, and fit surface over the plot

persp(my_grid$input_1, my_grid$input_2, my_grid$final_value)

Error in persp.default(my_grid$input_1, my_grid$input_2, my_grid$final_value) : 
  invalid 'z' argument
```

Alternative #2: Does Not Work

```
library(plotly)

a = my_grid[,c(1,2,5)]
fig <- plot_ly(a = ~as.matrix(a))
fig <- fig %>% add_surface()

Error: Must supply `z` attribute
```

Alternative #3 : Does Not Work - Creates an Empty Plot

```
plot_ly() %>% 
    add_trace(data = my_grid,  x=my_grid$input_1, y=my_grid$input_2, z=my_grid$final_value, type="mesh3d" )
```

**Problem:** Can someone please show me how to do this? Can this be done using the "lattice" or "rsm" libraries? Or can it be done using the ways I suggested?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get your plotly approach going, you need to configure your z as a matrix, i.e. an object with defined row and col dimensions!

Plotly does not require a dataframe. You can safely supply the variables (objects) directly.

```
library(plotly)

x <- my_grid$input_1
y <- my_grid$input_2
z <- matrix(my_grid$final_value, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y)) # proper matrix & dimensions

plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z) %>% add_surface()
```

and voila:

[image]

**amended answer based on question in comment - how to set on colorscale**

This is a bit hidden in the documentation. In principle, you can define your own colorscale with endpoints/colours for the gradient you prefer, and ensure it is scaled in accordance with your surface data. Surface data must be again a well-defined matrix, i.e. having nrow/ncol dimensions [check this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537977/color-surface-by-variable-with-plotly-in-r).

Typically, a colorscale is defined for the interval c(0,1). The [plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/r/reference/surface/#surface-colorscale) speaks about a mapping for the lowest (0) and highest (1) values. The 2nd element of colorscale is the definition of the spectrum end-colours! As an alternative, you use one of the accepted colour palettes.
This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573936/r-how-to-change-color-of-plotly-3d-surface) provides an example:

```
colorscale = list(c(0, 1), c("tan", "blue"))
```

So for the mapping you can use your min and max values.

```
# --- define coordinate vectors
x = input_1
y = input_2
z = matrix(input_3, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y)) # z must be well-dimensioned matrix

# --- define a scale for your colour setting
my_colorscale = list(
    c(min(final_value),max(final_value))    # set min/max value, or use c(0,1)
  , c("tan", "blue")                        # define desired grad. colours
)

# --- plot
plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z) %>% 
   add_surface(
       surfacecolor = matrix(final_value, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y))   # your surface data points 
      ,colorscale = my_colorscale)    # scale for your surface
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it possible to make the color of the surface represent "final_value"? I.e. a surface between "input_1", "input_2",  input_3"....and the color according to "final_value"? thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @Noob I amended my answer for setting the surface points and colorscale. Keep on rocking!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I was able to figure out another way of doing some slightly different!

Comment: X <- seq(0,100,1); Y <- seq(0,100,1); DF <- expand.grid(X,Y); DF$Z <- sin(DF$Var1) + cos(DF$Var2); Z <- matrix(DF$Z, nrow = 100); plot_ly(y = ~Y, x = ~X, z=~Z) %>% add_surface()

Comment: excellent. as mentioned, you do not need to work with data frames with plotly, but you can. Just make sure to use the "tilde" notation when you do. It cost me hours of my life chasing errors ... :). .... The important thing to keep in mind that you have to well-format your z-variable as a matrix with clear dimensions. Here your nrow is sufficient. Well spotted, Noob.